# (How) Can I resetify/correctificate odd Safari response?

Tags: safari, macos

I am running Safari (12.1.2) on an elderly version of Sierra (10.12.6) to maintain legacy software functionality. No more-recent version of Safari is available for the operating system installed.

Something is interfering with Safari.
Here are some symptoms:

- Some site pages hang on login.
- A favourite Wordpress blog has occasional unpopulated picture frames and comment 'submit' buttons.
- In Stackexchange—I can login; but, I cannot comment, up or down vote.
  I can answer questions but the markdown hints are missing from the answer text box header. The answer submit button is ineffective.
  The site's top strip banner is crippled (clicking the hamburger takes me to StackOverflow not Meta).

SE support suggested using a different browser after they found no irregularities on the server side.
It worked! Everything seemed normal on a different web client.

I am looking for a way (instructions, frankly) to fix Safari somehow without losing passwords, Top sites, bookmarks, etc. in the least destructive way possible

Comment: Anything that runs on Sierra would probably run on Mojave - which can use Safari 14, & so far isn't displaying 'out of date' issues.

Comment: Has the page loaded when you're using a website? (Is there a cross instead of the reload button?). If so, this happens for me sometimes but I just have to cancel reload/load and reload it (again).

Answer (score 1):

Safari 12.1 was released in 2018 (4.5 years ago), so many web technologies are in use today that do not work with Safari 12.1.

For Stack Exchange specifically, they support the previous two major versions of each browser, which would not include Safari 12.

You could diagnose the issue by making a new user account on the machine and seeing whether Safari works better in that account. I suspect it won't.

If it does fix it, comment and I'll edit this with more...